# how to pass more parameters toanother activity?

Tags: android

how do i  pass  more then 1 parameters to  pass anther activity?
i pass my 2D string as a paramter in this way which pass sucessfull but now i want two pass more parameters semrately now use bean class how do i sent??

```
 Intent j = new Intent(AgAppTransUtilityBalanceInquiry.this, AgAppTransUBIResponse.class);



         MyBean bean = new MyBean();
         bean.set2DArray(xmlResponse);
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("mybean", bean);

            j.putExtra("obj", b);

          and get like this

         Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("obj");
                   MyBean dData = (MyBean) b.getSerializable("mybean");
                   xmlResponse =dData.get2DArray();



         public class MyBean implements Serializable{
 String[][] data = null;
 public void set2DArray(String[][] data){
    this.data = data;
 }
 public String[][] get2DArray(){
    return data;
 }
  }


             but i want pass two more parameters

             b.putString("otheraccount", otheraccount.getText().toString());
           b.putString("choicess" ,(String)provider.getSelectedItem());

            how do i pass this two more parameters seprately??
```

Comment: u can use intent.putextras();

Comment: how does it not work ? passing 2 params is done the way you wrote it

Comment: but it not shows value in debug mode? i get 1 parameter in another activity by using 

 Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("obj");
                   MyBean dData = (MyBean) b.getSerializable("mybean");
                   xmlResponse =dData.get2DArray();
this code